# NodeJS - modifying one object from two different Node servers

Tags: arrays, node.js, object

Let's say I have an array in a node server at IP xx.xx.xx, let's call it mobile server because only mobile users can access it:

```
var users = [{username: "jim", stats: "x"}]
```

Now I have another node server at IP yy.yy.yy, for PC users only.

I want user "jim" to be able to access his user through HTTP requests from his PC and his mobile aswell, but also modify his object whenever he makes changes in one of the devices. is it possible to achieve, performance-wise and security-wise?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You would want both node servers to access the same db for simplicity. You can use any database, nosql (mongodb) or a traditional sql one (mysql, postgresql, etc).

Comment: On MongoDB, suppose I have mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
It will have to change to an IP now, right? and this might cause security issues, no? and where should my mongoDB be hosted, on one of my node servers?

Comment: Yes, you would need to specfiy the host if you decide to host mongodb on a different machine. You can setup your mongodb to use a username / password (this is recommended to do in any case) so security should be covered. I'm not sure why you are creating 2 node servers to be honest. Why not just go with one?

Comment: What happens if it won't be able to handle the loadage? I might need another server in the future, and then what?